Knowledge Articles Not Showing for Customer Community Login User
Hi Im trying to do this in experience cloud: Share knowledge articles by criteria with customer community login users and guest user. but I've been stucked here for about 8.5 hours already, since I have not been able even to open access to community login users.
This are the OWD for external (As you can see, PRIVATE):

This is my setup for data categories from setup

And this is my setup for data categories in the community user login custom profile:

However whenever I login as any user under that profile, I cannot see any knowledge articles.
Do you guys know, How can I share knowledge articles through criteria just as you do with any object in sales cloud?

Does this answer your question? Articles not visible to Salesforce Community members

Check if this may help you. - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8yvFSAR   - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8qnGSAR

@TusharJadav Do you know How data categories should work? is this restrictive does this overwrite OWD external sharing settings?

You can refer to this helpful documentation. - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.category_whatis.htm&type=5   - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387727&type=1
